# Convert JavaFX Node, Group or Shape3D to Mesh

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-8, javafx-3d

Is there any possible way to convert JavaFX `Node`, `Group`, or `Shape3D` to `Mesh`?

I need this to export my scene to '.obj' and the only exporter I found (in FXyz library) requires `Mesh`.

Comment: Every 3D node in your scene could be transformed into equivalent objects with a known mesh, and these could be exported. Is this what you are looking for? What kind of objects do you have?

Comment: @JoséPereda, I think so. It at least seems like a step in a good direction. I use `Sphere` and `Cylinder` objects.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have?

Comment: @JoséPereda, this is part of bigger project, so it may be hard to understand at first, but let's consider this class: http://shoutkey.com/east . There's `Group root` which contains all 3D objects I use. To be specific `VisualizedConnection` and `VisualizedNode` objects, which extends `Cylinder` and `Sphere`.
If I knew how to convert each of this objects to `TriangleMesh` I would manage I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem when using built-in `Shape3D` nodes like `Sphere`, `Cylinder` or `Box` is those don't expose their `TriangleMesh`.

If you need that mesh, there are several options:

1. Create your own implementation of that shapes, where you provide the mesh
2. Use [FXyz](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz) library equivalent shapes instead, so you will have already the mesh in all of them
3. Stick to built-in `Shape3D` nodes if this is a requirement, but before exporting them, transform them to equivalent shapes from the FXyz library, so you can access their meshes.

In terms of exporting the model, the current `ObjWriter` in FXyz only exports one mesh at a time, so you can:

1. Export all the shapes to their own .obj file
2. Modify ObjWriter in order to export a list of meshes to a single file (you are welcome to create a pull request to FXyz if you do)
3. use `MeshHelper` to create one single mesh (only one material could be applied), and export it to a single .obj file.

I'll assume the third case in both situations, creating a new `TexturedMesh` object, based in all the 3D shapes found on the scene. This will have a single mesh that can be exported to an obj file. Notice you need `FXyzLib.jar`.

```
class EquivalentMesh extends TexturedMesh {

    private MeshHelper mh = null;

    public EquivalentMesh(Parent root) {
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        addShapes3D(root, nodes);

        transformAndMerge(nodes);
    }

    // Transform Built-in Shape3Ds to a single TexturedMesh
    private void transformAndMerge(ArrayList<Node> nodes) {

        nodes.stream().forEach(shape -> {
            TriangleMesh tm = null;
            if (shape instanceof Sphere) {
                Sphere sphere = (Sphere)shape;
                SegmentedSphereMesh sm = new SegmentedSphereMesh(sphere.getRadius());
                sm.setCenter(new Point3D((float)sphere.getTranslateX(), (float)sphere.getTranslateY(), (float)sphere.getTranslateZ()));
                tm = (TriangleMesh)sm.getMesh();
            } else if (shape instanceof Cylinder) {
                Cylinder cylinder = (Cylinder)shape;
                FrustumMesh fm = new FrustumMesh(cylinder.getRadius(), cylinder.getRadius(), cylinder.getHeight());
                Affine affine = new Affine();
                cylinder.getTransforms().forEach(affine::append);
                javafx.geometry.Point3D ini = affine.transform(new javafx.geometry.Point3D(0, cylinder.getHeight()/2, 0));
                javafx.geometry.Point3D end = affine.transform(new javafx.geometry.Point3D(0, - cylinder.getHeight()/2, 0));
                fm.setAxisOrigin(new Point3D((float)ini.getX(), (float)ini.getY(), (float)ini.getZ()));
                fm.setAxisEnd(new Point3D((float)end.getX(), (float)end.getY(), (float)end.getZ()));
                fm.setSectionType(TriangleMeshHelper.SectionType.CIRCLE);
                tm = (TriangleMesh)fm.getMesh();
            } else if (shape instanceof Box) {
                Box box = (Box)shape;
                CuboidMesh cm = new CuboidMesh(box.getWidth(), box.getHeight(), box.getDepth());
                cm.setCenter(new Point3D((float)box.getTranslateX(), (float)box.getTranslateY(), (float)box.getTranslateZ()));
                // TODO: apply rotations
                tm = (TriangleMesh)cm.getMesh();
            } else if (shape instanceof MeshView) {
               tm = (TriangleMesh)((MeshView)shape).getMesh();
               // TODO: apply transformations 
            }

            if (mh == null) {
                mh = new MeshHelper(tm);
            } else {
                mh.addMesh(new MeshHelper(tm));
            }
        });

        // create single mesh
        updateMesh(mh);
    }

    private void addShapes3D(Parent parent, ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        for (Node node : parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            if (node instanceof Shape3D) {
                nodes.add(node);
            }
            if (node instanceof Parent) {
                addShapes3D((Parent)node, nodes);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateMesh() {
        // no-op
    }

    // export to obj and mtl
    public void export(String nameFile) {
        OBJWriter writer=new OBJWriter((TriangleMesh) getMesh(), nameFile);
        writer.setMaterialColor(Color.RED);
        writer.exportMesh();
    }

}
```

In order to test it, let's create a simple scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(100);
    sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
    Box box = new Box(50,50,50);
    box.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));
    box.setTranslateX(300);
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(2, 300);
    cylinder.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.GREEN));
    // Transformations applied:
    cylinder.getTransforms().addAll(new Translate(150, 0, 0), new Rotate(90, Rotate.Z_AXIS));

    Group group = new Group(cylinder, sphere, box);
    StackPane root = new StackPane(group);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    // export as single mesh
    EquivalentMesh equivalentMesh = new EquivalentMesh(root);
    equivalentMesh.export("group");
}
```

[image: Initial scene]

Notice that by creating a new instance of `EquivalentMesh`, now we have a single mesh and we can export it, generating `group.obj` and `group.mtl` files.

Finally, using [3DViewer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/fe6b492b9150/apps/samples/3DViewer) to import the obj file, this is what you'll get:

[image: 3DViewer obj file]